# type of determinism of an evironment

Tags: artificial-intelligence, deterministic, non-deterministic

Studying the environment where an agent has to work, I have to tell about it's determinism.

> An environment is deterministic if the next state is perfectly
>   predictable given knowledge of the previous state and the agent's
>   action

Otherwise it's non-deterministic.

My question is: What if I know that the next state is one of few I can calculate, but I can't tell exactly which? Is it still non-deterministic? Or it is a different type of determinism?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which possible resulting states there are, and you know the associated probabilities, it is still said to be non-deterministic. This is assuming that there actually are probabilities involved (for instance, rolling a die and transitioning to a state depending on the outcome of rolling that die).

If you don't know which possible resulting states there are, and/or you don't know the associated probabilities, it is also said to be non-deterministic. For example, this is the case if you are rolling an unfair die, where not every outcome has an equal probability, and you do not know in which way it is unfair (is the "1" more likely? or the "6"?).

If there aren't any probabilities involved in the state transitions, but you simply don't know the rules that determine to which state you transition, it is deterministic. For example, this can be the case in a game where you need to explore the map to figure out where an opponent is located. In this case you say you have incomplete information.